# Web crawler finds data as object and won't let me manipulate it

Tags: php, web-crawler

I have solid but basic understanding of HTML, CSS, javascript, Sql, and PHP. I thought it would be cool to build a website since I have most of the skills I need. The overall purpose of the site requires a web crawler to extract price data from finance websites. The web crawler itself is a little advanced for me so I used a pre-made one from the following link http://cdn.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/my-first-crawler.zip?3cb89b . My code is as follows:

```
 <?
if(count($_POST)>0){ 
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$tickerSelected = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"tick");  
$url_tick = $tickerSelected;
if($url_tick !=""){           //MAKE SURE SOMETHING IS IN THE FIELD
$target_url = "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/$url_tick"; 

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);


foreach($html->find('h1[id=instrumentname]') as $name){
//$text = convert_html_to_text($name);
print $name;

}
foreach($html->find('p[class=data bgLast]') as $dollar) //THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS
{
print $dollar; //<--I WANT TO MANIPULATE THIS NUMBER INSTEAD OF ONLY BEING ABLE TO PRINT IT
}

}
else
print"<h2>Please Enter a Ticker</h2>";
}

?>
```

Using the webcrawler to print out the information has been a success. So there is not issue in the setup. Instead the problem is that I cannot figure out how to turn the ticker price which is returned as $dollar into a floating point number. If I want to do any math with the returned stock value an error is returned (below).

Notice: Object of class simple_html_dom_node could not be converted to int.

Anyway, I am a finance major so this stuff is all new to me (however, it is cooler than finance..) I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: there are many stock API's use one of those, don't crawl sites that don't want you to.

Comment: The title of this is very  misleading.  You're looking for string to float manipulation, and youre talking about web sites and web crawlers....

Answer (score -1):

Go to the official documentation. There is an example [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/#fragment-12)

Comment: link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.